# Replace Shopify Checkout Placeholder

Tags: css, shopify

I want to change the placeholder text for a specific Shopify Checkout element.

I'd like to replace "Street and house number" and translate it to Catalan. There is no way in the system to translate this string, so I think maybe I'd be able to replace it with some CSS?

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

first, you need to hide the default placeholder

```
input[name=INPUTNAME]::placeholder {
  color:transparent;
}
input[name=INPUTNAME]:-ms-input-placeholder {
  color:transparent;
}
input[name=INPUTNAME]::-webkit-input-placeholder {
  color:transparent;
}
```

then you need to use ::before with content to mimic placeholder
something like this

```
input[name=INPUTNAME] + label::before{
content:'new place holder text';
position:absolute;
top:0;//position placeholder
left:0;// position placeholder
pointer-events: none;//make it not clickable so user can interact with input
// font size and style must be same as the input 
/// color must match the placeholder color
}
```

because input doesn't support :: before you have to use :: before with input parent or an element that immediately follows your input
if HTML code is like this

```
<div class="input">
   <input/>
</div>
```

use

```
.input::before
```

if HTML code is like this

```
<input/>
<label></label>
```

use

```
input + label::before
```

"+ label" means the first label that comes after the input

the problem could be to hide the placeholder when the input is empty or the user is in focus. the best scenario is when input is followed by an element like a label

```
input[name=INPUTNAME]:focus + label::before,input[name=INPUTNAME]:not(:placeholder-shown) + label::before{
  display:none;
}
```